# How can I use URLLOader to read a blob from a private container?

Tags: apache-flex, azure

I have a flex application which is hosted on Azure.

I have some data stored in a blob in a private container.

How can I use URLLoader to display the data? If I use a public container , 
then I am able to read from the blob in my application. 
However, if the type of the container is private URLLoader fails.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: I'm a noob on Azure, but isn't the whole point of having a private container is that it's not accessible from external sources?  I would imagine that's why the URLLoader fails.

Answer (score 1):

Azure provides a SharedAccessSignature method to allow you to temporarily allow third parties to access blobs via HTTP.

This sample code from `SetPermissions` on MSDN shows you how to create a shared access policy - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee758387.aspx

```
// Get the shared access signature to share with users, specifying a signature-level access policy.
string sas = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessPolicy()
{
    SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.Now,
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(10),
    Permissions = SharedAccessPermissions.Write | SharedAccessPermissions.Read
});
```

Once you have a shared access policy then it is basically a query string to add on to the end of your normal HTTP GET URL

Answer (score 0):

You may need to look at Blob Container Access Policies and Signed Blob URL. You can define a time range to container access policies (can have upto 5 container access policies) for a time period you want to allow access. Windows Azure allows to generate signed blob url using container access policies. You can also create a signed blob url without using container access policy, but that url will be valid for a maximum of one hour. 
Generated signed blob url allows access to the blob even if blob container is private. 
Please find more information from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee393341.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee395415.aspx).